# redirect to login page if user is not logged in?

Tags: php, redirect, yii

i used beforeAction Method for redirection in Controller class for redirecting. when i redirect to login page using $this->redirect method , its not working .

**The page isn't redirecting properly**`

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    {


        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('user/login/login')); 

        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return true;
    }

    //something code right here if user valided
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please define "not working"

Comment: it will redirect to the login page .

Comment: I think you have to change login url of your user module in `/config/main.php`

Comment: could you please tell me how i can do so ???

Comment: well paste your `/config/main.php` so it can be examined

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->url;
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('/site/login'));
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors if you add some explantion of your intention.

Comment: what about this line 
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->url;  i tried your code but it didn't work.

Comment: if i put any redirect in method within beforeAciton method then redirect method stop working . only "The page isn't redirecting properly " is showing in the browser , on the other hand , url is right

Comment: may i know your login page url

Comment: $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('user/login/login'));

Comment: i have created user module and under user Module i have created login controller and within this controller i created a method login

Comment: browser url for login page

Comment: if i comment the $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('user/login/login'));  in beforeActin method within Controller class then i will run

Answer (score 0):

Here is main.php

```
<?php
```

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(**FILE**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'EMS',
    //'defaultController' => 'user/login/login',

```
// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',


    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
    'application.modules.user.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'admin',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
    'user',


),


//default theme

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
         'class' => 'WebUser',
         'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
         //'loginUrl'=>array('user/login'),
    ),
    'authManager' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID' => 'db'
    ),



    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

    /*'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),*/
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yiiems',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'atinekd@ebizneeds.com',
),

'behaviors' => array(
        'onBeginRequest' => array(
                'class' => 'application.components.RequireLogin'
        )
),
```

);